# Why does the formatting for lines of 10 in a for loop come out wrong at the console?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, line

I typed in the following code in eclipse, and expected rows of ten characters per line. However, I cannot figure out why the first and last lines only have 3 characters. Can anyone help?

```
package chapter4;
import java.util.*;

public class DisplayChars {

    public static void printChars(char c1, char c2, int num){

        for(int i = (int)c1; i <= (int)c2; i++){
            if(i % num == 0)
                System.out.println("");

            System.out.print((char)i);
        }           
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter two characters and the number per line");

        char c1 = (char)input.next().charAt(0);
        char c2 = (char)input.next().charAt(0);
        int numberPerLine = input.nextInt();

        printChars(c1, c2, numberPerLine);
    }
}
```

And the output is as follows:

```
please enter two characters and the number per line
a
z
10
abc
defghijklm
nopqrstuvw
xyz
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The character code for `a` is 97.  You see the characters `a` through `c` on one line because that's characters 97-99.  Then `d` through `m` is 100-109, `n` through `w` is 110-119, and `x` through `z` is 120-122.

To get 10 on a line to start with, don't use `i` as indicator to determine when to print a newline.  Use another variable for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You start counting from 'a', not zero. And notably, 'a' % 10 is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

In ASCII a=97 so after 3 iterations you encounter d=100. And in the last line your loop ends so last 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is that when the first character is "a", the int value of a is not a multiple of 10, so (i % num) likely evaluates to 7 on the first iteration of the loop, leading to only 3 characters being printed on the first line.  You could rewrite it like this:

```
public static void printChars(char c1, char c2, int num){
    int count = 0;
    while (c1 <= c2) {
       System.out.print(c1);
       count++;
       if (count == num) {
         count = 0;
         System.out.println("");
       }
       c1++;
    }
}
```